# main function returns 3221225477 althought it compiles and runs as it's supposed to

Tags: c++, return

This program runs a menu where the user is using keys. It runs as it is supposed to, but for some reason it returns a ridiculous value. I thought I messed up with `break`s in the `switch` sequences, but nothing was wrong. I'm confused, because it prints out `"All WHILE cycles passed"` which means the next step is to return 0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define ENTER_KEY 13
#define ESC_KEY 27
#define ERASE cout << "                                                                          "

struct MENU
{
    char text[50];
    int id;
    int color;

    void menu_print(char* text)
    {
        cout << text << endl;
    }
};

void set_color(int color);
void gotoxy(int x,int y);
int id_track(struct MENU *lines ,int amount_of_lines ,int x ,int ESCapable);

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int highlight = 13; 
    int highlight_warning = 12;
    int highlight_accept = 10;
    int _default = 7;
    
    set_color(_default);

    // Here "int highlight" is ASCII code for pink color. "int highlight_warning" and "int highlight_accept" are not used yet. "int _default" is ASCII code for white.

    //######################################################################
    MENU main_lines[2];

    int main_amount = 3;
    int main_escape = 0;

    strcpy(main_lines[0].text,"1.Start work");
    main_lines[0].id = 0;
    main_lines[0].color = _default;

    strcpy(main_lines[1].text, "2.Help");
    main_lines[1].id = 1;
    main_lines[1].color = _default;

    strcpy(main_lines[2].text,"3.Quit");
    main_lines[2].id = 2;
    main_lines[2].color = _default;

    // Lines user sees first

    //######################################################################
    struct MENU work_lines[4];

    int work_amount = 5;
    int work_escape = 1;
    
    strcpy(work_lines[0].text,"#1.1 Action 1");
    work_lines[0].id = 0;
    work_lines[0].color = _default;
        
    strcpy(work_lines[1].text, "#1.2 Action 2");
    work_lines[1].id = 1;
    work_lines[1].color = _default;

    strcpy(work_lines[2].text,"#1.3 Action 3");
    work_lines[2].id = 2;
    work_lines[2].color = _default;

    strcpy(work_lines[3].text,"#1.4 Action 4");
    work_lines[3].id = 3;
    work_lines[3].color = _default;

    strcpy(work_lines[4].text,"#1.5 Action 5");
    work_lines[4].id = 4;
    work_lines[4].color = _default;

    // Lines user will be able to interact after selecting the START WORK line

    //#######################################################################

    bool main_menu_active = true;
    bool sub_menu_active;

    while (main_menu_active)
    {
        switch(id_track(main_lines ,main_amount ,5 ,main_escape))
        {
            case 0:
                main_menu_active = false;

                sub_menu_active = true;
                while(sub_menu_active)
                {
                    switch(id_track(work_lines ,work_amount ,15 ,work_escape))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            gotoxy(50,2);
                            cout << "Work in process";
                            break;
                        
                        case 1:
                            gotoxy(50,3);
                            cout << "Work in process";
                            break;
                        
                        case 2:
                            gotoxy(50,4);
                            cout << "Work in process";
                            break;
                        
                        case 3:
                            gotoxy(50,5);
                            cout << "Work in process";
                            break;
                        
                        case 4:
                            gotoxy(50,6);
                            cout << "Work in process";
                            break;
                            
                        case ESC_KEY:
                            sub_menu_active = false;
                            main_menu_active = true;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                gotoxy(15,3);
                cout << "Help triggered";
                break;

            case 2:
                main_menu_active = false;
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    // Traces lines that user is able to select

    cout << endl << "all WHILE cycles passed" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void set_color(int color) //sets color - ASCII input value
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
}

void gotoxy(int x,int y) //Sets cursor on asked position
{
    COORD c;
    c.X=x;
    c.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),c);
}

int id_track(struct MENU *lines ,int amount_of_lines ,int x ,int ESCapable)  
{
    int key_pressed;
    int current_pos = 0;
    bool RUN = true;

    int i;
    int highlight = 13;
    int _default = 7;
        
    amount_of_lines = amount_of_lines-1;
        
    while (RUN)
    {
        key_pressed = 0;

        for (i=0;i<=amount_of_lines;i++)
        {
            if (current_pos == ((lines+i) -> id))
            {
                set_color(highlight);
            }
            else
            {
                set_color(_default);
            }
            
            gotoxy(x,i+2);
            (lines+i) -> menu_print((lines+i) -> text);
        }

        switch((key_pressed = getch())) 
        {
            case KEY_UP:
                if (current_pos < 0)
                {
                    current_pos = 0;
                }

                if (current_pos > 0)
                {
                    current_pos--;          
                }
                break;

            case KEY_DOWN:
                if (current_pos > amount_of_lines)
                {
                    current_pos = amount_of_lines;          
                }

                if (current_pos < amount_of_lines)
                {
                    current_pos++;
                }
                break;

            case ESC_KEY:
                if (ESCapable)
                {
                    for (i=0;i<=amount_of_lines;i++)
                    {
                        gotoxy(x,i+2);
                        ERASE;
                    }
                    RUN = false;
                    return ESC_KEY;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                
            case ENTER_KEY:
                RUN = false;
                set_color(_default);
                return current_pos;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Function returns on which line user pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, variable `ESCapable` defines if user can press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to return to previous menu.

Here are the images of the program:

Working as it supposed to:

[image]

Cursed return value:

[image]

Comment: You create an array `main_lines` with 2 elements, but then access 3. You create an array `work_lines` with 4 elements, but then you access 5.

Comment: HRESULT [3221225477](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225477).

Comment: I think that code means access violation. However I am going by memory. My advice is when you see a strange number like this google it.

Comment: It looks like the out-of-range access destroyed the return address and returning from `main()` with the broken address caused access violation.

Comment: Exit code 3221225477 is hex `0xC0000005`, which indeed is an Access Violation exception.  The code is trying to access invalid memory and crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you have to specify the number of elements, not the maximum index, when declaring arrays.

Therefore, `main_lines[2]` for `MENU main_lines[2];` and `work_lines[4]` for `struct MENU work_lines[4];` are out-of-range, so you must not use them.

Allocate enough elements like `MENU main_lines[3];` and `struct MENU work_lines[5];`.